# Changing legend names without changing colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to rename the values in a legend without altering the custom colors that have already been set. Is there a way to set legend labels without using scale_color_manual? Currently, I have something like this:

```
norm <- rnorm(1000, 0 , .5)
gam <- rgamma(1000, 2)
beta <- rbeta(1000, 2, 3)
dist <- data.frame(Normal = norm, Gamma = gam, Beta= beta)
dat <- melt(dist, variable.name = "Distribution", value.name = "XValue")
plot1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(XValue, color = Distribution)) +
            stat_density(geom = "path", position = "identity", size = 2) +
            scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow", "black", "forestgreen"))

plot2 <- plot1 + scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Distribution 1",
                                "Distribution 2",
                            "Distribution 3"))
```

This however overwrites the manual colors. I will be changing the names in a different function from where I am setting colors so, unfortunately, I will not be able to use scale_color_manual( values =... , labels = ...). The other option I thought of is to somehow get the colors used in plot1. I could then do something like:

```
colors <- plot1$colors_used
plot2 <- plot1 + scale_color_manual(labels = c("Distribution 1", 
                                               "Distribution 2",
                        "Distribution 3"),
                                      values = colors)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to specify the label names in `scale_colour_manual`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(XValue, color = Distribution)) +
  stat_density(geom = "path", position = "identity", size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow", "black", "forestgreen"),
                     labels = c("Distribution 1",
                                "Distribution 2",
                                "Distribution 3"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately, I'd much rather not refactor. Renaming the labels will be done in a separate function. This function will be taking many different plots that all have unique colors. The plots (along with colors) will be created in many different functions. I would like to be able to just apply this function to determine the new names and then rename. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know how can change the color of the Label "Distribution" here ?

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question: "Is there a way to set legend labels without using scale_color_manual?" If it is not possible, your answer should be "no". @joran this is clearly a MWE, you don't know how the OP's code is factored.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a consistent color palette, then you could define this as:

```
    mycolors <- c("red", "blue", "black", #ee4747, #fff382, #f1f6c8, #334d65, #263825)
```

Now, instead of

```
    values = c("yellow", "black", "forestgreen")
```

use

```
    values = mycolors
```