# Change legend names in ggplot2 without changing function colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data1 %>% 
gather(key, value) %>% 
ggplot(aes(value, color=key)) + 
  stat_ecdf(size=0.8) + xlim(-4.5,4.5) + 
  labs(x = "t(α)", y = "Probability", color="Legend", labels=c("Actual","Simulation"))
```

which produces the following output:

[image: CDF plot]

My problem is that I would like to keep the colors from the current ggplot theme (theme_gray), but at the same time be able to manually set the legend/label names. I am aware of a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848036/changing-legend-names-without-changing-colors-in-ggplot2) written by a Mr. Taylor. However, the answer marked as most helpful are defining the colors manually. In this project, I am going to have plots with multiple functions, hence I would like ggplot to just use its build-in theme's colors in order to keep the colors consistent throughout the project.

I have tried versions of

```
scale_colour_manual(values=c("color1","color2"), labels=c("Label1","Label2")
```

but I am unable to just name the legends without also having to define colors.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: `scale_colour_discrete(labels = c("Label1","Label2"))`

Comment: Perfect, exactly as I wanted! Thank you very much, Mr. @JackBrookes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale_color_discrete(labels = ...)`.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 2), y = c(1:10, 6:15), leg = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)))

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = leg)) + 
  geom_line()

g
```

[image]

```
g + scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Actual", "Simulation"))
```

[image]

In most cases however, it's probably better to change the values in the column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(leg = recode(leg, `A` = "Actual", `B` = "Simulation"))
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    x  y        leg
1   1  1     Actual
2   2  2     Actual
3   3  3     Actual
4   4  4     Actual
5   5  5     Actual
6   6  6     Actual
7   7  7     Actual
8   8  8     Actual
9   9  9     Actual
10 10 10     Actual
11  1  6 Simulation
12  2  7 Simulation
13  3  8 Simulation
14  4  9 Simulation
15  5 10 Simulation
16  6 11 Simulation
17  7 12 Simulation
18  8 13 Simulation
19  9 14 Simulation
20 10 15 Simulation
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on your initial answer. As mentioned, the plots now work as intended. Have a nice weekend.